# Call different methods in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, tkinter, methods

I am creating a dice generator to learn tkinter. Its my first time, so bear with me. I am also attempting to make everything within a class, though I haven't shown all the code, since theres a lot. **The end goal is to be able to input 'x' amount of 'y' type of dice (4,6,8 sided dice, etc, and calculate the total.** Rather than create a button individually for each type of dice, I am trying to use a for loop to simplify it.

```
class DiceRoller:
    def __init__(self,root):
```

There is lots of code at the beginning, but the following is all within the above method.

```
self.diceNames = ['D4','D6','D8','D10','D12','D20','D100']

    for x in range(len(self.diceNames)):

        #DEFINE TEXT FOR ENTRY BOX
        self.entryText = 'Roll '+self.diceNames[x]
        #CREATE ENTRY BOX
        self.entryBox = ttk.Entry(self.rollButtonFrame, 
                            width=self.entryWidth,
                            textvariable = self.textvariable).grid(row=self.rollRowStart+x,column=self.entryCol)
        
        #CREATE BUTTONS
        ttk.Button(self.rollButtonFrame, text = self.entryText,
                                         command = self.rollDice).grid(row=self.rollRowStart+x,column=self.rollCol)
        #CREATE LABELS FOR ANSWERS
        ttk.Label(self.rollButtonFrame, text = 'Total: 0').grid(row=self.rollRowStart+x,column=self.answerCol)
        #CREATE LABELS FOR DESCRIPTIONS
        descText = 'Number of '+self.diceNames[x]+' dice: '
        ttk.Label(self.rollButtonFrame, text = descText).grid(row=self.rollRowStart+x,column=self.descCol)
                                         command = self.rollDice).grid(row=self.rollRowStart+x,column=self.rollCol)
```

This creates the buttons, labels, and entry boxes properly, [(see here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXZY8.png) however I can't figure out how to call a different method for each of the dice. I also don't know if that's the best way to do this. **How can I make each button behave differently depending on the input, while also creating the buttons in  a for loop as shown?**

I thought if I could make a list of methods it would work, but I don't know if its possible.

Is there a much better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have two `for x in range(len(self.diceNames)):` loops, is that intentional?

Comment: I recommend you get out of the habit of looping like `for x in range(len(list))`. Instead, use `for item in list:`

Comment: @Barmar removed the redundant for loop, that was unintentional. I usually use for item in list, but for some reason I didn't here. Is there a great advantage in this specific case?

Comment: It just makes the code easier to write and understand, nothing specific to this case.

Comment: `for x, item in enumerate(self.diceNames)` is better as you need the `x` in `grid(...)`.  Also, you use same `self.textvariable` for the `textvariable` option of all the entries.  It will make all the entries having same content if one of the entries is updated.  Use separate variable for each entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for this:

```
# This assumes self.rollDice takes the name of the target die as the first argument
(ttk.Button(self.rollButtonFrame, text=self.entryText, command=partial(self.rollDice, self.diceNames[x]))
    .grid(row=self.rollRowStart + x, column=self.rollCol))
```

`partial` creates a *new* function by binding some of the arguments ahead of time.  Just to give another example of how this works:

```
roll_d20 = partial(self.rollDice('D20'))
roll_d100 = partial(self.rollDice('D100'))
d20_result = roll_d20()  # This is the same as `d20_result = self.rollDice('D20')`
d100_result = roll_d100()  # This is the same as `d100_result = self.rollDice('D100')`
```

You could use a lambda to accomplish the same thing:

```
(ttk.Button(self.rollButtonFrame, text=self.entryText, command=lambda name=self.diceNames[x]: self.rollDice(name))
    .grid(row=self.rollRowStart + x, column=self.rollCol))
```

However this method has a common [gotcha](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result) related to Python's lexical scoping rules, hence the need for the default argument `name=self.diceNames[x]`.  I personally prefer `partial` because I always end up forgetting about this behavior with lambdas.

Comment: Looks like there is also a partialmethod method. Is this better in this situation? As I am unfamiliar with partial, where do I define the partial functions? I think I understand your code. For example, where would I actually put the roll_d20=partial(…)?

Comment: `partialmethod` is also used to partially bind function arguments, but the difference is that it leaves room for a `self` parameter so the resulting function can be used as a class method.  So for example you could use that instead if you wanted the bound function to be called like `self.roll_d20()` or `myDiceRoller.roll_d20()`.  In this case it seems like you don't need that form, since you only care about setting up the button callback.

Comment: To answer your second question, you can assign the partial function to a variable, you could pull all of them into a `list` or `dict`, or you can just do the binding inline like in my first example.  In the example you've given, it doesn't really matter outside of personal preference.  But if you want to reuse these bound functions elsewhere, that might influence your decision.